# While unsitalling the Windows mobile application , how to Keep SQL CE Database with Existing DataOn device?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows mobile 6 application.When a new patch is Available on server it will download the New Cab file and install progrmatically on the device with the below Code

```
Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "\"" + Path.Combine(applicationPath, updateFileName) + "\"");
  proc.WaitForExit();
```

But this is deleting The existing Database[Sql CE] and Valuable Datas also.

I need to keep the Database On device and uninstall the application and install the new cab file where no need to install the Fresh DB again along with NEW cab installation...

How can i achieve this...help me on this????

Comment: I removed the Windows Phone 7 tag because it is a different architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before unstalling, backup the database file (typically .sdf). After the installation, replace the new database file with your backup.

```
// backup the CE database
string databasePath = ""; // location of your database
string backupPath = ""; // choose a backup path
try
{
    File.Copy(databasePath, backupPath);
}
catch 
{
    Trace.TraceError("Error creating backup");
}


Process proc = Process.Start("wceload.exe", "\"" + Path.Combine(applicationPath, updateFileName) + "\"");
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Then, after re-installation, delete the new CE database and restore your backup:

```
if (File.Exists(databasePath))
{
    try 
    {
         File.Delete(databasePath);
    }
    catch 
    {
         Trace.TraceError("Error deleting new database");
    }
}

string databasePath = ""; // location of your database
string backupPath = ""; // choose a backup path
try
{
    File.Copy(backupPath , databasePath);
}
catch 
{
    Trace.TraceError("Error restoring backup");
}
```

If you can't delete the new database because it is in use, you'll need to come up with a mechanism to work around that (for example, renaming the new DB, then copying your backup, and then rebooting your application/device)

Comment: can i do this pro-grammatically ? C# code example will be most useful to me...please help me

Answer (score 0):

The code by [digginforfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466903/diggingforfire) will allow you to prevent this database from being deleted.

Personally, though, I think it is better to write code that ensures this is not necessary. For example, your application should check for the database's existence in the `Application Data` folder before it attempts to load it. If the database is not there, you simply create it.

Copying and modifying a version of Microsoft's example found [>> HERE <<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase%28VS.71%29.aspx), you'd have something like this:

```
string appPath = string.Format(@"{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}",
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "MyCompany", "MyProduct"
  );

string dbFile = "database.swf";
string dbFilePath = Path.Combine(appPath, dbFile);
if (!File.Exists(dbFilePath)) {
  string connStr = string.Format("Data Source={0}; Password ={1}", dbFilePath, "1234567");
  using (SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr)) {
    engine.CreateDatabase();
  }
  using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr)) {
    try {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 int, col2 ntext)", conn)) {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    } catch { } finally {
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

This will ensure that the database remains after your product is uninstalled.

Comment: But, the above code will only create new database right sir? i need the existing valuable data along with the Database.How to keep the Database still in Application Folder ,and while application reinstalls,dont install the Fresh DB with it instead the existing DB.

Comment: Yes, the code will create a new database if one is not available. Otherwise, it will use the database that is already there. By having your app create the database in code as opposed to installing it via the CAB installer, the database will not be removed whenever the application is uninstalled.

Comment: Also, whenever you install an update to your application, again, the database is already there, so it just starts using the database. If you have other questions, please ask!

Comment: Sir it sounds gud...But...i want to install new cab on device...at this time ,how can we prevent only local database from deletion[While Uninstallation]. and where i put this code for, checking if local db is  already available in Device.....if you dont mind please give me the steps to test it ....

Comment: Back up your database first, like **dinggingforfire** said. My version is only to prevent you from having to do manual database backups on your next project(s).